# How to auto-generate column names in Microsoft Form

Tags: microsoft-forms

Recently I have created a Microsoft Form with the following columns:

1. Name (Text)
2. DOB (Date)
3. State (Choice)
4. Age (Number)

When I have collected the responses and converted it to Excel sheet, I found few more auto-generated columns present in the excel sheet.

1. ID
2. Name
3. Start Time
4. Completion Time
5. Email
6. Last Modified Time.

With an extra name column auto-generated, the **Name** column I added was renamed to **Name2**. I believe the columns are pretty valid for auditing purposes.

Any idea how to control this behaviour? I need to stop genarating these columns or they could be renamed to something  I wish?

[image: Form Excel Sheet]